# Reuse React Native screens across applications

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, create-react-app, react-component

Most of the applications have similar login and sign-up screen with the option for user to navigate between them. The user first lands on login screen and post login is taken to landing screen. If they don't have an account,  they can click on "sign-up" link on login screen.
I don't want to duplicate this in all applications, rather use them from a common library.

How can I put the login and sign-up screen with navigations as reusable component (or local npm package) in react native with some props (like the landing screen post login)?

I am moving from Xamarin, where this was fairly easy, create a .NET standard library with the XAML for both the screens and use them across all the applications.
Didn't find a way to achieve the same in react native.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I will only reuse the UI part between project. As you said you need a component for each of your screens: Login Screen, Create Account Screen etc.

**Those components should be:**

- stateless
- should use props (for customization, for callbacking your app when a button is pressed etc)
- should not depend on your project
- The logic should be implemented in your project, not in those components (e.g the login request)
- Also if you use Redux, your component should not directly depend on it
- If your components need data from the Redux Store, use Redux Containers, which should be part of your app not of your lib

**Finally, as you said you can publish your components on npm ;)**

Comment: Thanks Daniel for you response. Can you provide more details like a blog post, code sample etc? The sample I could find only talks about creating reusable UI components (like button or progress bar). Did not find any help with creating reusable UI screens across multiple react native projects.